# How to extract coefficients of polynomial formatted like this?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, polynomials

I want to extract coefficients.

```
Subscript[x, 1, 2] + Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[x, 4, 2] 
{ {{1,2},1} , {{4,2},Subscript[a, 2]}  } 


Subscript[x, 1, 2]
{ {{1,2},1}  }


Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[x, 4, 2]
{  {{4,2},Subscript[a, 2]}  }


Subscript[x, 2]
{ {{2}, 1}  }
```

How to extract the coefficients?
I tried `CoefficientList` and `CoefficientRules`, but I failed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
Subscript[x, 1, 2] + Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[x, 4, 2] //
Apply[List] //
# /.a_. * Subscript[x, m_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ ] :> {{m,n},a} &
```

> {{{1, 2}, 1}, {{4, 2}, Subscript[a, 2]}}

```
Subscript[x, 1, 2] /.a_.* Subscript[x, m_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ ] :> {{m,n},a}
```

> {{1, 2}, 1}

notice missing a bracket.

```
Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[x, 4, 2] /.a_.* Subscript[x, m_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ ] :> {{m,n},a}
```

> {{4, 2}, Subscript[a, 2]}

Answer (score 1):

## Succinct verion

Thanks to the help of @AsukaMinato

```
Clear["Global`*"];
hasMultipleTerms[expr_] := ListQ[expr /. Plus -> List];
transformExpression[expr_] := 
  Module[{isMultipleTerms, myOptionList, resultToBeRefined}, 
   isMultipleTerms = hasMultipleTerms@expr;
   myOptionList = If[isMultipleTerms, List @@ expr, expr];
   resultToBeRefined = 
    myOptionList /. 
     a_.*Subscript[x, subsripts__] :> {List[subsripts], a};
   If[isMultipleTerms, {#} & /@ 
     resultToBeRefined, {{resultToBeRefined}}]];

transformExpression[
 Subscript[x, 1, 2] + Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[x, 4, 2]]
transformExpression[Subscript[x, 1, 2]]
transformExpression[Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[x, 4, 2]]
transformExpression[Subscript[x, 2]]
transformExpression[Subscript[x, 2, 3, 5]]
```

## Previous version

So verbose, whereas definitely true...

```
Clear[getCoefficients]
getCoefficients[expr_] := 
 Module[{terms, coefficients, matched, unmatched, result, k},
  result = {};
  terms = expr /. Plus -> List;
  If[ListQ[terms] == False,
   {matched1 = 
     Cases[{terms}, 
      coeff_*Subscript[x, subscripts__] :> {List[subscripts], coeff}];
    matched2 = 
     Cases[{terms}, 
      Subscript[x, subscripts__] :> {List[subscripts], 1}];
    (*Print[{terms}];
    Print[matched1,"match",matched2];*)
    If[Length@matched1 == 1, {result = result~Append~matched1, 
      Return[result];}];
    If[Length@matched2 == 1, {result = result~Append~matched2, 
      Return[result];}];
    Return[result];},
   {For[k = 1, k <= Length@terms, k++,
     term = terms[[k]];
     matched1 = 
      Cases[{term}, 
       coeff_*Subscript[x, subscripts__] :> {List[subscripts], coeff}];
     matched2 = 
      Cases[{term}, 
       Subscript[x, subscripts__] :> {List[subscripts], 1}];
     (*Print[{term}];
     Print[matched1,"match",matched2];*)
     If[Length@matched1 == 1, {result = result~Append~matched1, 
       Continue[]}];
     If[Length@matched2 == 1, {result = result~Append~matched2, 
       Continue[]}];
     ];
    Return[result];}
   ];
  result
  ]


getCoefficients[
 Subscript[x, 1, 2] + Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[x, 4, 2]]
getCoefficients[Subscript[x, 1, 2]]
getCoefficients[Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[x, 4, 2]]
getCoefficients[Subscript[x, 2]]
```